# Build failure when buidling hpi for jenkins buildpipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

installed Java 1.6 in my centos and was building buildpipeline plugin in commandline. hpi was created, but it is showing the following error

```
 Tests run: 71, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-license-plugin:1.7:process (default) @ build-pipeline-plugin ---
 [INFO] Generated /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build- pipeline-plugin/WEB-INF/licenses.xml
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-hpi-plugin:1.95:hpi (default-hpi) @ build-pipeline-plugin ---
 [INFO] Exploding webapp...
 [INFO] Copy webapp webResources to /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build-pipeline-plugin
 [INFO] Assembling webapp build-pipeline-plugin in /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build-pipeline-plugin
 [INFO] Generating hpi /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build-pipeline-plugin.hpi
 [INFO] Generating /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build-pipeline-plugin/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 [INFO] Building jar: /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build-pipeline-plugin.hpi
 [INFO] Building jar: /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/target/build-pipeline-plugin.jar
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.6:check (default) @ build-pipeline-plugin ---
 [INFO] Starting audit...
 /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/src/main/java/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/BuildPipelineView.java:32: Using the '.*' form of import should be avoided - hudson.model.*.
 /root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/src/main/java/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/BuildPipelineView.java:422:19: Variable 'context' should be declared final.
 Audit done.

 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 06:41 min
 [INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-12T07:05:12-08:00
 [INFO] Final Memory: 35M/89M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.6:check (default) on project build-pipeline-plugin: Failed during checkstyle execution: There are 2 checkstyle errors. -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

i tried with java 1.8 also, build failure happens. please help me to solve this to build the hpi for jenkins buildpipeline plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your build failed the checkstyle validation, as indicated by this error message:

```
Failed during checkstyle execution: There are 2 checkstyle errors.
```

The first issue in question is in:

```
/root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/src/main/java/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/BuildPipelineView.java
```

Where on line `32` you used `.*` to import everything under the `hudson.model` package.
Being more specific and importing only what's needed should help you to get rid of this error, so use:

```
import hudson.model.Action;
import hudson.model.Item;
// etc.
```

rather than:

```
import hudson.model.*
```

The other error sits in:

```
/root/IdeaProjects/build-pipeline-plugin-master/src/main/java/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/BuildPipelineView.java
```

where on line `19` you declared variable `context` but haven't declared it as `final`.

Hope this helps,

Jan